# How do I create a Perl regular expression to remove all characters before the first "<"?

Tags: regex, perl

I currently have this: `tr/[.]+(?=<)//d` which should remove all characters (represented by `[.]+`) up to the first `"<"`, because I'm using a positive lookahead. But for some reason, it's removing all `"."` and `"<"` from the string.

For the record, I am not processing HTML or XML with regular expressions.

Comment: Why are you using regex to parse HTML?

Comment: I'm not. The log details (error level, time stamp, etc) is separated from the message by a <. I only care about the message, so I want to strip everything else.

Comment: The `tr` method doesn't do meta-chars. You can't put a regular expression into it.

Comment: It might be wise to put up a disclaimer for people like myself who might think it's about *ML parsing.

Comment: That's a good point though. You shouldn't be using regex to work with HTML or XML. It can only lead to problems...I edited my question to reflect that I'm not doing that.

Comment: You use `[.]` if you want to match a literal `.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning of characters change when used in [] as a character class. [.] has no meaning, really, different from just . so the . is interpreted literally in that context.

I think this should work just fine:

```
$text =~ s/^.*?</</s;
```

Comment: just /s is probably all that is needed - see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers -- if the first < is not on the first line, we want the . to match new lines.

Comment: It's not a big deal, but with .* at the beginning of a regex, you don't need a beginning of string anchor.

Comment: Note that you don't need the non-greedy specifier.  s/^[^<]*</</ will work fine too, without getting beyond the "simple subset" of regexes that everyone knows.  I guess the choice is a matter of style.

Answer (score 6):

You do not want [`tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cds).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    last unless /\S/;
    s/^.+?</</;
    print;
}

__DATA__
a < b < c
a < b < c
```

Comment: The substitution operator, `s///`.

Answer (score 3):

```
^[^<]+
```

`.` (dot) within the character class is a literal dot, not a wildcard.

Comment: @SilentGhost No need to do anything if there are no characters before `<`.

Comment: @SilentGhost in general, it is not a good habit to use `*` when you mean `+` due to issues with backtracking and unexpected matches.

Answer (score 3):

The '.' in a character class is not a meta-character. Also you want `s///`, not `tr`, which replaces single characters. so `s/^.+(?=<)//` should work, although personally I would write
`s{^.*<}{<}`, to avoid the lookahead thingie.

Comment: @mirod No need to do any replacements if there are no characters before `<`.

Comment: There is no need to, I just find s/^.+(?=<)// harder to read. I have to pause and remember that ?= is a positive lookahead, My brain can parse s{^.*<}{<} much faster

Comment: There is also no need for lookahead. Either `s/^.+?</</` or `s/^[^<]+//` is cleaner.

Comment: Indeed, s/^[^<]+// is quite nice

Answer (score 1):

Edit as it was clarified:

```
if ($line =~ /^.+?<(.+)/) {
  push @matched, $1;
}
```

Comment: @Oesor Have you tried this code with lines that have more than one `<` in them?

Comment: Sinan: Good point. I just relooked at this, and if I have a log message with a < in it (for some reason), then I might get unexpected results.

Comment: I'm not thinking today -- .*? would be correct and only match to the first <, yes?

Comment: @Oesor: Yes. Also, anchoring the expression and using `+` when you mean `+` are better practices.

Comment: The * was intentional -- nowhere in the initial post was it stated that the < couldn't be the initial character in the string, just that he wanted the bit after the initial <